# How to read .pptx file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have a file path ('storage/emulated/0/first.pptx'). How can i read this file within the app. I tried different packages. but not found any perfect solution.

Comment: If you will share the errors you are getting it would be easy to help.

Comment: I tried different packages like 1) power_file_view 2) file_reader...... but these packages have some issues like engine load failed etc. So now i want to try in another way if someone guides me .